# How to do nested cursor in sybase ase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

May I ask how to properly do a nested cursor in sybase? 
I'm getting two errors in my code below.

1. Must declare variable @notes
2. Declare cursor must be the only statement in a query batch.

Current coding attempt:

```
DECLARE c3 cursor FOR
select distinct cust_ac_no from tempdb..M3_SHP_ACCOUNT_NOTES
where cust_ac_no in ('851243048')
--,'851261620
--order by cust_ac_no, inst_seq_no, ord_no, ref_no, acv_no
GO

DECLARE 
@exec_str1 varchar(8000),
@exec_str2 varchar(8000),
@cust_ac_no varchar(10),
@c_ac varchar(10),
@notes varchar(4000),
@notes2 varchar(8000)

--select @exec_str1 = "select distinct notes from tempdb..M3_SHP_ACCOUNT_NOTES where cust_ac_no = "

OPEN c3
FETCH c3 into @cust_ac_no

WHILE @@sqlstatus = 0

  BEGIN

  DECLARE c2 cursor FOR
  select distinct notes from tempdb..M3_SHP_ACCOUNT_NOTES
  where cust_ac_no = + "'" + @cust_ac_no + "'"
  order by cust_ac_no, inst_seq_no, ord_no, ref_no, acv_no
  GO


  OPEN c2
  FETCH c2 into @notes

  WHILE @@sqlstatus = 0
  BEGIN

  print @notes

  FETCH c2 into @notes  
  END
  CLOSE c2
  DEALLOCATE c2

  print @cust_ac_no
  FETCH c3 into @cust_ac_no
  END

CLOSE c3
DEALLOCATE c3
```

Comment: For batch processing you need a method of passing data across the batch ('go') boundaries; one example would be using a temp table to hold said values; in this scenario the nested cursor would be defined to join `M3_SHP_ACCOUNT_NOTES` with the temp table, and during execution you would truncate/re-populate the temp table before each `open C2`;if you have the permissions to create a stored proc then you **can** place all of your code (both cursors, @variable references in cursors) in a single stored proc (eg, create proc, exec proc, drop proc)

Comment: @markp sorry but can u show sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Based solely on the code provided, it looks (to me) like this could be done with a single cursor.

Assumptions:

- while the example shows only one `cust_ac_no`, the use of the `'in()'` clause leads me to think we may need to process a list of `cust_ac_no`'s, so I'll write this to support multiple `cust_ac_no`'s in a list
- the sample code shows a `cust_ac_no` being printed **after** the associated `notes` have been printed

One possible single-cursor solution:

```
declare c3 cursor
for
select distinct
       cust_ac_no,
       notes
from   tempdb..M3_SHP_ACCOUNT_NOTES
where  cust_ac_no in ('851243048')  -- could be multiple cust_ac_no's
order by cust_ac_no, inst_seq_no, ord_no, ref_no, acv_no
go

declare @cust_ac_no        varchar(10),
        @cust_ac_no_prev   varchar(10),
        @notes             varchar(4000)

select @cust_ac_no_prev = NULL

open c3

fetch c3 into @cust_ac_no, @notes

while @@sqlstatus = 0
begin
    if @cust_ac_no_prev is NULL
        select @cust_ac_no_prev = @cust_ac_no

    -- print cust_ac_no *after* its associated notes have been printed;
    -- this should be done when we fetch a new cust_ac_no:

    if @cust_ac_no_prev != @cust_ac_no
        print @cust_ac_no_prev

    print @notes

    fetch c3 into @cust_ac_no, @notes
end

-- print the last fetched cust_ac_no:

print @cust_ac_no

close c3
deallocate c3
go
```